# Redirecting to parameters in Destroy Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So my addresses model has an `:id` field and a `:person_id` field.

My destroy function is as follows

```
def destroy
    @addresses = Address.find(params[:id])
    @addresses.destroy
    redirect_to _______
end
```

How do I redirect back to the `:person_id`

If this helps explain it better, the
URL's are as followed

**/people/1111111**

then I delete and it goes to the address id

**/address/212212/delete**

then I need to go back to the person id

**redirect back to /people/1111111**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should save the people before

```
def destroy
    @addresses = Address.find(params[:id])
    @person = @addresses.person 
    @addresses.destroy
    redirect_to people_path(@person)
end
```

I think that this should work for you